# If exists, update is getting timeout from using ExecuteNonQueryAsync() in C# Azure Function from about 450k rows in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am getting a timeout error from using `ExecuteNonQueryAsync()` to do an update if something exists. The table that I am doing the update has about 450k rows so I wonder if this has something to do with it.

Below is the query

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.File_Tracker WHERE file_name = @filename)
    UPDATE dbo.File_Tracker SET
        file_purge_indicator = 'Y'
        , file_purged_time = @file_received_time
        , file_purgedby = @file_purgedby_duplicate
    WHERE file_name = @filename and file_purge_indicator = 'N'
```

The following is the error that I am getting. I would like to know why this is happening and how to fix it.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalEndExecuteNonQuery(IAsyncResult asyncResult, String endMethod, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryInternal(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryAsync(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
```

Comment: 450K rows should be nothing... unless the relevant indexes are missing.

Comment: I added the query.

Comment: Do you have an index on FileName? If not its going to have to scan all 450K rows...

Comment: I do not.. Do you think that might be the problem?

Comment: Um yes :) as I said above, your query is going to be scanning all 450K rows to check whether the filename exists or not.

Comment: You don't need the `if exists` condition, you have a `where` clause.

Comment: Omg you're right! LOL

Comment: Wait, I need the if exists because sometimes the file name does not exist. I don't want to trigger the update statement.

Comment: Why not? The point of a `where` clause is to only update matching records, if there isn't a matching record nothing gets updated.

Comment: You're combining procedural programming with set based programming when you can do everything set based.

Comment: But won't the update query takes longer than the If exists(select..). Because now we are doing an update every single time instead of doing a select first.

Comment: No, in fact you are slowing down a regular update because it has to repeat the lookup twice, once in the `if exists` and once in the `update`. The `update` works the same as the `select` in terms of how it finds the record to update in the first place. When there is no match you are still carrying out the same lookup just in a separate bit of code.